# How do I loop through csv file rows and remove all excess spaces?

Tags: python, csv, read.csv

This is my first python project so my apologies if this is a silly question. I want to loop through the rows of some csv files I created and replace all excess spaces with a single space, and then replace those spaces with commas so I can make my columns.

Here's where I am so far:

```
for new_files in os.walk(target): #"target" is a desktop folder. Only contains .txt and .csv files
for new_name in new_files:
    raw_filename=os.fsdecode(new_name)
    raw_file=target+'\\'+new_name
    os.chmod(target,stat.S_IWRITE)
    if new_name.endswith('.csv'):
        for row in csv.reader(open(raw_file)):
            while row.contains('  '):
                str.replace('  ', ' ')
    else:
        continue
```

I get the following error:

```
filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Here is a sample of a csv file I am trying to edit (in the raw file there is variable spacing between each value, and they're all in column A of an excel spreadsheet):

```
Ch= a 
[ 1222 20940 85 -49 -11 284 5191 -2] 
Ch= a 
[11772 2319 116 -50 -10 302 5190 -2] 
Ch= a 
[1634 513 187 -49 -10 1051 5190 -2] 
Ch= a 
[ 370 470 1863 -49 -10 11516 5189 -2] 
Ch= a 
[ 294 374 9674 -50 -11 2048 5190 -2] 
Ch= a 
[ 345 490 5238 -50 -10 479 5190 -2]
```

Comment: It would help if you can show a portion of your file. If your files contain sensitive data, create some made-up sample.

Comment: Hello, yes here's a snippet that pretty much encapsulates it:
Ch= a
[ 1222 20940    85   -49   -11   284  5191    -2]
Ch= a
[11772  2319   116   -50   -10   302  5190    -2]
Ch= a
[1634  513  187  -49  -10 1051 5190   -2]
Ch= a
[  370   470  1863   -49   -10 11516  5189    -2]
Ch= a
[ 294  374 9674  -50  -11 2048 5190   -2]
Ch= a
[ 345  490 5238  -50  -10  479 5190   -2]

Comment: I forgot to ask. Given that input, what is your expected output?

Comment: By the way, the input you have is not a CSV file, so you cannot use the `csv.reader` to read it. Also, do you want to write out the result into a different file or the same file?

Comment: The eventual output is to have all values in their own column, with "ch=A" removed. For now I'm just trying to remove the extra spaces between values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using Python 3, so I am going to use the `pathlib` library, which is easier to use than the `os` one.

```py
import csv
import pathlib


root = pathlib.Path("~/temp/csv_files").expanduser()
for path in root.glob("*.csv"):

    # Read a text file, convert text lines to row (a list of strings)
    rows = []
    with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
        for line in stream:
            if line.startswith("Ch="):
                continue
            row = line.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split()
            rows.append(row)

    # Write the rows
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
        writer = csv.writer(stream)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Notes

- Replace the root with your own directory
- Instead of `os.walk()`, I use `.glob()`, which is more convenient
- I assume you want to convert the text file into CSV in place, meaning to write the output to the same file, replacing the old contents

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
PATH = "path/to/folder"
for old_files in os.listdir(PATH):
    if old_files.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(f"{PATH}/{old_files}", "r") as f1:
            lines = list(
                map(
                    lambda x: x.strip(),
                    filter(lambda x: "Ch= a" not in x, f1.readlines()),
                )
            )
        with open(f"{PATH}/new_{old_files}", "w") as f2:
            for l in lines:
                m = re.search("(\[\s?)(.*)(\s?\])", l)
                f2.write(m.group(2).replace(" ", ","))
                f2.write("\n")
```